# PHP return !$ret (Return NOT)

Tags: php, return

I was looking at the PHP hash_equals() function here: https://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php

I came across the following code:

```
function hash_equals($a, $b) {
    $ret = strlen($a) ^ strlen($b);
    $ret |= array_sum(unpack("C*", $a^$b));
    return !$ret;
}
```

What does `return !$ret` return?

Edit:  I know "!" is the logical operator "NOT".  However, I wanted to know what it's doing to the return value.  Does it return the opposite of the value, or make it false?  I read the entire duplicate that this post is linked to, and still don't understand.

Comment: And that you don't search forever in the list it's the logical NOT operator.

Comment: Whatever value ends up in `$ret`, in that context, the `!` coerces it to a boolean value and inverts it. So truthy values return boolean `false`, and falsy values return boolean `true`.

Comment: Refer to [PHP's type comparison table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for what values are considered true/false.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I thought it maybe reversed it, but now that I understand it "coerces" it to a boolean value, it makes sense.